# Reducing latency for different geographic regions on Amazon Cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have got an application which has three components

- Application code : Amazon EC2 US-EAST-1 instance
- Application images, and other static data : Amazon S3 with CloudFront
- Application Database : Amazon RDS

In short i need something like Cloud Front for EC2.

In long, people using this application from a different region say middle east will have faster static content downloading due to Cloud Front but there would be a lot of latency in communicating to EC2 instance. I want to use a budget friendly way of enhancing this. Launching Amazon Instances in every region that offer is sure a choice, but isn't really cheap, so would try to avoid it unless its last resort.

Also say if my clients also need to communicate to the RDS database directly, is there some kind of solution which gives that kind of functionality mentioned above, but for RDS?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a good way to reduce geographically induced latency beyond distributing servers geographically.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a caching server in each geographic region which would speed things up. Varnish is really popular for this. And you could use a hosted service like [fastly.com](http://fastly.com)